# Send email with Microsoft Flow when Power BI alert is triggered

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I am trying to build a flow that sends an email to me, when a Power BI alert is triggered. I have build the flow, and now trying the test option.

This gives me a Status code error 429

Addional details:

**Headers**

```
Retry-After: 600 
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: deny 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff    
RequestId: ad5eb81f-a02d-4edd-b0c2-964cef662d01
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
x-ms-apihub-cached-response: false
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 12:35:42 GMT
Content-Length: 254
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Body**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "MicrosoftFlowCheckAlertStatusEndpointThrottled",
    "pbi.error": {
      "code": "MicrosoftFlowCheckAlertStatusEndpointThrottled",
      "parameters": {},
      "details": [],
      "exceptionCulprit": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I noticed this 429 is caused by too many requests, but I do not understand this, since I only have 1 alert, and this is a very simple Flow thats connected to this 1 alert, and should then send an email.

Answer (score 0):

In general `Error 429` means you have exceeded the limit of triggers per period (probably `60 seconds` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/powerbi/ ). You should find these parameters in `Peek code` tool.

My suggestion is to check how many alerts for the data tracked you had in Power BI service. Too low limit might be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

It was appearing when testing manually.
When I changed the testing to "Automatic" the error changed and it was clear that the "Send an e-mail" step caused the issue.
It turned out that the second step needed to change to Outlook - Send an email (V2) step.

It was really confusing as the MicrosoftFlowCheckAlertStatusEndpointThrottled was irrelevant and it was not the real issue!